# List in model to controller to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning MVC 5 and I can't find the reason why I can't reach the List of names in the View? I'm sure I have done something wrong, but I can't see why and would preciate some help to be able to continue.

In the Controller I have tested to use `ViewBag` and pass the List with return and then use `@Model`.

Model Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVC_1.Models
{
    public class ListNames
    {
        public static List<string> names;

        // Constructor
        public ListNames()
        {
            // Create list
            names = new List<string>();
            // Add some names to list
            names.Add("Anna");
            names.Add("Linda");
            names.Add("Petra");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ListNames(List<string> Names)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = Names[0];

        return View(Names);
    }
```

View:

```
@model MVC_1.Models.ListNames

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListNames";
}

<h2>ListNames</h2>

<p>@ViewBag.Name</p>

<p>@Model.????</p>
```

Comment: Top Tip : Don't bother with `ViewBag`. Use a strongly-typed viewmodel (a `class` associated with the view). In my experience, using `ViewBag` can make things difficult to follow, and sometimes causes hard to spot bugs - such as not realising that an object, or property, has not been initialised.

Comment: Your model is a list, so you need to iterate over it in in your view in order to display the elements.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. Your GET method should not have a parameter `List<string> Names` (you initialize your model within the method). You have show a model `ListNames` but never use it anywhere. And your not passing the correct model to the view (you pass `List<string>` to a view expecting typeof `ListNames`)

Comment: Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `get` and `set` to the list inside the model;

```
public class ListNames
{
    public List<string> names { get; set; }
    //rest of the code
}
```

As @stephen-muecke mentioned you action returns `List<string>` and the view is expecting the `ListNames` model. A solution will be like below

```
public ActionResult ListNames()
{
    var listNames = new MVC_1.Models.ListNames();
    ViewBag.Name = listNames.names[0];

    return View(listNames);
}
```

View:

```
@model MVC_1.Models.ListNames

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListNames";
}

<h2>ListNames</h2>

<p>@ViewBag.Name</p>
@foreach(var name in Model.names)
{
   <p>@name</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the your code, but I can't still don't get a value with @Model. ?? Should there not be something like @Model.Names? Let's say I want to make a for each loop, then I would need to use something like ....1< Model.Names.Length??

Comment: @front-back You have to iterate over `Model.names` with  `foreach` or others.

Comment: Sorry, but I get a red line below this line: <p>@name</p> What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @front-back My bad, i forgot `@` in front of `foreach`.

Comment: When I run the code I get a Null Exception Reference at the @foreach.... line :( Is the list empty!? Is it wrong to add names to the list like I do in the constructor with Add("Linda") ? Since the List now is a Property? I appreciates your help!

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to return the listNames to the View! Now it's working! Great! So the correct way is to create an object inside of the method in the Controller and not create an object inside of the own class then!? Seems correct when I think about it.

Comment: @front-back You think good, the correct way is to create/populate the object in the action (not in the view).